# Android testing - Problems caused by state persisting across application instances

Tags: android, testing

When running android connected device tests, state that persists across application instances, such as permissions and files stored by the application, cause tests to interfere with each other.

For example, if I want to write a test for application behaviour when I deny runtime permissions and another test for application behaviour when I allow runtime permissions, then I must be very careful that the tests run in the correct order. If the allow test ran before the deny test, then the deny test would fail, because the permissions settings would already have been granted.

Another example, in a shopping app, the application may store the contents of the basket in the apps internal file storage to allow the basket to survive application termination and reboots. Testing the behaviour of the shopping basket then becomes very difficult, as the tests interfere with each other.

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Be sure to clean up the state after each test case. Tests which depend on the order run are considered a bad practice. In a lost of cases, you can implement a `teardown()` method (annotated with `@AfterTest` if you are using JUnit4) to do the clean up.
2. Create mock state objects during tests that can be injected into your app. I'm still new to this particular approach, so I don't have a lot of advice here. Some googling should help you get started.

Comment: teardown will work for most things, but is there a way to remove granted permissions?

Comment: @B4Z How are the permissions granted? Are you talking about `<uses-permission>` in your manifest?

Comment: I do have a <uses-permission> in my manifest, but with Android 6.0 permissions are granted at runtime. So my application pops up a dialog asking the user to allow/deny the permission.

Comment: @B4Z I am unable to find any information about revoking permissions that have already been granted. A possible workaround is to group your tests (possibly using annotations) and then run each group separately and be sure to completely uninstall your app between each group run.

Comment: Ordering of tests can be done in some cases, but in others I do not believe that it can. For example, if the tests are in different classes, I don't think that it's possible to specify the order.

Comment: Also, I haven't looked into this but I think that it is very unlikely that Android would let you uninstall the app and reinstall it programmatically from a test.

Comment: @B4Z You are correct. You cannot do this with Java code in a JUnit test. But you certainly can from Gradle or any other build tool or shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking the state / Injecting special state objects for the tests is a solution for most problems but not the Runtime permission case

Comment: Providing mock objects is also hard when testing activities. Android forces activities to have default constructors, meaning that dependencies are much harder to inject.

Comment: In the shopping basket example, you only want one instance of this object per application. So you would likely have some static way to retrieve this object (perhaps from a custom Application class). Because it is static, it cannot be mocked without something like PowerMock.

Comment: @B4Z Don't make it static. e.g. Dagger2 provides solutions to having 'singleton' instances of objects without actually using static methods or singletons. You just need to take good care handling dependencies

Comment: hi, i would like to get your attention to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539960/how-to-get-release-build-apk-file-using-proguard, your help would be greatly appreciated